# How to evaluate efficiency of ContentProviders in Android?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have few questions related to Android framework that I couldn't find either on [android developer's site](http://developer.android.com/index.html) or somewhere else. So, I'm tempted to ask here.

I was asked these question's in an interview that:

**How will you evaluate the efficiency of `ContentProviders` in Android ?**

**How much time does it take if you want to fetch 3000 Contacts ?
Will it take same time if you want to fetch email's of the contacts as well?**

Comment: It seems to just be a question about the time difference of querying for one column in a table, and querying for more than one. And that ought to just boil down to a DB question, specifically, sqlite, in this case, since that is the format in android, by default. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: 1) "efficiency" has no defined meaning. You can answer whatever you want. 2a) Depends on the device & how fast it is. 2b) Impossible to know without knowing the database schema. And in case of `ContentProvider` even less because those don't need to have a database at all. They could be backed by a RESTful webservice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question

> How much time does it take if you want to fetch 3000 Contacts ?

-> Depends on the device speed, anyway the time complexity is linear in input size: ***O(n)***

Second question

> Will it take same time if you want to fetch email's of the contacts as
>   well?

-> AFAIK The emails of the contacts are in the *data* table, a sub section of *raw contact*, and each contact could have more than one email, so probably you need more time to get all emails of all contacts compared to get only the contacts.

> The Contacts Provider is an Android content provider component. It maintains three types of data about a person, each of which corresponds to a table offered by the provider, as illustrated in

[image]

More details [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html)

Answer (score 1):

> How will you evaluate the efficiency of ContentProviders in Android ?

That will be evaluated by query latency. So you can measure the worst time for a query that is possible, compare it with your app requirements and see if it would cause a considerable wait time for user.

> How much time does it take if you want to fetch 3000 Contacts ?

Run the code and measure. Would be different on different devices and versions.

> Will it take same time if you want to fetch email's of the contacts as well?

Email and rest types of "data" is probably [in same table](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html). Each record is per MIME-type of data, so "email" would require an extra record fetch. A well formed query can fetch data of multiple types in a single go, then its up-to cursor processing code to differentiate between it.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a select * from table question.  Answer It's more efficient to select (columns you need) from table.

The best case senario for reading from a content provider is achieved when the projection contains only the columns you intend to use and you have a well coded loop to read the data.

if you pass null for the projection it will take the same amount of time because all columns of the content provider will be returned to both calls.

If on the first call you pass key_id for the projection and the 2nd pass you pass {key_id, key_email} the 2nd pass will take more time because the content provider is returning more data

The actual time depends on how well you code loops and what you do with the data in the loop.  For example if every loop you do a getColumnIndex("email") it will take a lot longer than an optimized program that determines the column indexes before entering the loop.

Notice there is no moveToFirst() this is the fastest read loop for sqllite the first call to moveToNext() does the moveToFirst() for you.

```
 if (cursor !=null) {
    //get column indexes here
 while (cursor.moveToNext()){   //processing here }
 }
 cursor.close()}
```